# Spawning rigidbodies with velocity

Tags: instantiation, velocity, godot, gdscript, rigid-bodies

So I am making a gun in a Godot game. I want to use rigidbodies for the bullets, and it spawns like normal out of the gun. However, I cannot seem to find a way to spawn the rigidbody bullets, with velocity. Here is my code so far, I would love some help with this! (I am using gdscript, and I am new to Godot):

```
extends Position3D

signal spawned(spawn)

export(PackedScene) var spawnling_scene

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("leftClick"):
        spawn()

func spawn():
    var spawnling = spawnling_scene.instance()

    add_child(spawnling)
    spawnling.set_as_toplevel(true)


    emit_signal("spawned", spawnling)
    return spawnling
```

Comment: Is the spacing/formatting correct in your code sample the way it is displayed? The way it is displayed here, the portion of the `spawn` function that actually adds the instance to the tree isn't actually included in the function. I was going to fix the formatting, but if this is how it actually looks in your script that might be part of the issue? Can you please either [edit] to fix the formatting, or confirm that this is exactly how it is in Godot?

Comment: What actually happens? Do the bullets spawn and appear, but don't move? Or do they not appear at all?

Comment: They do appear, and move, but i cant figure out how to spawn them with a set velocity

Comment: Sorry! I didn't see the formatting error! I have now edited it to be the same as my code

Answer (score 2):

You can write the `linear_velocity` of the `RigidBody3D` before you add it to the scene tree. Here is a quick example:

```
extends Position3D


func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    var bullet := preload("res://scenes/bullet/bullet.tscn")
    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_accept"):
        var bullet_instance := bullet.instance() as RigidBody
        bullet_instance.linear_velocity = Vector3.RIGHT * 50
        add_child(bullet_instance)
        bullet_instance.set_as_toplevel(true)
```

---

> how do I make it so that instead of going in one direction, it goes in the direction that I face?

The `Basis` of the transform has the direction of the axis. Since we usually use the z axis as forward direction in Godot, usually the z axis of the `Basis` is the direction it is facing:

```
bullet_instance.linear_velocity = global_transform.basis.z * 50
```

Comment: Thanks loads, but how do I make it so that instead of going in one direction, it goes in the direction that I face?

Comment: I have now faced another problem (sorry to bother again, I am new to godot), but it only goes horizontally, and not up and down. Is there a fix?

Comment: @FluffyPancakes1 It should be able to go in any direction. Yet, I don't know how you are managing orientation, and I only have a limited of your scene. I don't have information to solve it. Consider opening a new question explaining what is going on.